# upload input not triggering click event

Tags: jquery, input, click

all console logs and alerts are happening but the button is still not being actually clicked.

```
init: function() {

    $('input[type=file]').change(function() {
      $(this).closest('.btn-upload').toggleClass('active');

      $('#button-submit').click(function() {
        console.log("event listening")
      });

      $('#button-submit').click();
    });

}


<div>  
<input type="file" id="button-upload">
<input type="submit" id="button-submit">
</div>
```

Comment: I think Dan has you sorted, but do yourself a favor and use more succinct ids ;)

Comment: haha its drupal ids ;)

Comment: its still not working, any thouoghts?

Comment: is there a form that wraps these inputs?

Comment: yes these inputs are in a fieldset and that fieldset is in a form

Comment: What happens if you call `$('formSelector').submit();` with the selector for your actual form instead of `$('#button').click();`, does it submit then?

Comment: If that submits the form, like Dan mentioned, you need to remove the `e.stopPropagation();` generally, that is used to prevent the form from being submitted, usually because the developer intends to process the form submission via ajax

Comment: its using ajax to submit just the file that was uploaded

Comment: Where is the code for the ajax, is it inside `$('#button-upload').click(function() { });`  or in some other handler? and if `console.log("event listening")` is fired as you say in your comments, then what makes you say that the button is not being clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching your event handler to and clicking the file input not the button as you're missing `-button` from the end of your selectors.

Should be:

```
init: function() {

$('input[type=file]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.btn-upload').toggleClass('active');

  $('#edit-submitted-student-membership-student-id-upload-upload-button').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("event listening")
  });

  $('#edit-submitted-student-membership-student-id-upload-upload-button').click();
    alert('asdfdf');
});

}


<div>  
    <input type="file" id="edit-submitted-student-membership-student-id-upload-upload">
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submitted-student-membership-student-id-upload-upload-button">
</div>
```

Comment: it still wont click it :(

Comment: I assume it is outputting "event listening" to the console? Try removing the `e.stopPropogation()` line as this will stop other handlers from firing and will block the submission of the form.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Submit the form? If so, I wonder whether you would be better off doing something like `$('#YourFormID').submit()` in the change handler rather than trying to click the button.

Comment: Btw now your question has 2 elements with the same ID of button.

Comment: its using ajax to submit just the file that was uploaded

Comment: You haven't included your AJAX code in your question. If that is being written to the console then the button is being clicked. It seems your problem is in code not included in your question.